# Nested views with ui-router in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am having some issues with a third level nested view/route using ui-router. I am essentially developing a site admin panel for all the sites I manage. on the "tools" page you first have to select an environment which populates the "sites" view and dropdown box once a site is selected you should get the "selected" view and panel which will contain all the site specific info. The issue I am having is the "selected" panel shows up when the "sites" panel shows up (without having selected a site yet).

My real question is this what is the proper way to setup multiple nested views using ui-router? do all the view get specified under each state? also is it ok to change the URL with a view change or should the url only be altered during a state change. I think I am mixing up states and views. I know that what I really want is a "tools" state/page with multiple views (one for each set of options).

even if someone could just provide some links to good tutorials on nested views and routes using ui-router that would be awesome.

I will try to setup a plunker to demonstrate what I am trying to do, but it has proved difficult so far being that I started with ng-boilerplate for this project

Comment: This kind of "large code issue" will work if you will provide working (partially) working plunker.

Comment: @RadimKöhler Your Right, and setting this up in plunker is proving to be a pain. Let me rephrase the question to get what I am really looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following video on egghead.io which got me to understand the basics of ui-router. https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-introduction-ui-router

Not sure how I didn't find this before asking my question. Maybe I should look harder next time.

UPDATE:

Also after doing some further research, I determined what I was really in need of was an abstract state, and was also able to find some info on that via egghead.io (its pro content, but I had been meaning to sign uo anyway) https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-ui-router-abstract-states